# How to avoid XSS and CSS but allow users to use some HTML tags?

Tags: php, security, xss

I need a way:

1. to lets users to use ONLY `<strong>` and `<p>` tags.
2. to avoid users to use CSS with these tags ( for example this must NOT works: `<p style="margin:1000px;"> hello </p>` ).
3. to avoid XSS.

   - `htmlspecialchars` is not sufficient because it convert all tags in html entities.
   - `strip_tag` is not sufficient because it allow CSS in the tags.

So what PHP functions can I use to do this ?

I **don't want** to use an external library like html purifier.

Comment: how does your user input the HTML ? by a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE ?

Comment: yes, the user can use a wysiwyg editor or insert tags manually.

Comment: For TinyMCE, it can setup a list of allowed HTML tags: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements can filter out junks. But for manual input, can't help.

Comment: @shivan: still need to do server-side cleanups, otherwise someone will always try to slip in a tag through the back door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best idea I can think (within the boundaries you require) is to use a custom string of text for `<p>` and `<strong>` and then `str_replace` it with the HTML tags on output. This way they can't inject anything dodgy.

You see this on a lot of forum websites when writing a post, where the user's can click paragraph and bold icons and it will put `[p][/p]` instead of `<p></p>`. Then on output str_replace `[p]` with `<p>` and `[/p]` with `</p>`. If they put any custom CSS or scripts in, then the `string_replace` would fail and not output any HTML that the browser would render.

Comment: I agree with that..another option is to use markdown syntax like stackoverflow: [http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own little lexer and parser for this very limited subset of HTML:

```
$input = '…';
$tokens = preg_split('~(</?(?:p|strong)\s*>)~', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
var_dump($tokens);

foreach ($tokens as $i => &$token) {
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        // text
        $token = htmlspecialchars($token);
    } else {
        // tag
    }
}
$output = implode('', $tokens);
```

Comment: very smart implementation. but if the input HTML is huge, it will consume a lot of RAM ( huge array ).

Answer (score 0):

The Web adopted solutions like MarkDown Language, exactly for these purposes.

Maybe you should implement a Markdown Editor on the client side and a Markdown decoder on the server side. It will permit your users to format their texts but block them, at the XSS / CSS point of view.

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

K.

Comment: OP does not want external libraries.